# Firebase customToken workflow (ICW Angular2 & Express)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to handle the creation of a customToken with Firebase in a secure way.

This is what I came up with:

1. The user logs in on the client side with email and password. `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`
2. Storing the current UID of the user in local storage. `localStorage.setItem('uid', response.uid);`
3. Get the JWT token of the current user. `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)` and store the token in localStorage `localStorage.setItem('token', res)`
4. Make a post call to the server and add the token to Authorization header and send the UID in the body. `const headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('token'));
   this.http.post('/api/login', localStorage.getItem('uid'), {
     headers: headers
   })`
5. On the serverside verify the token `const authorization = req.headers.authorization; admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authorization)`. If valid set the UID `this.uid = decodedToken.uid;`
6. Now generate the custom token. Add the additionalClaims `const additionalClaims = {
   premiumAccount: true };` and call the createCustomToken function. `admin.auth().createCustomToken(this.uid, additionalClaims)`
7. Send the custom token back to the client `res.status(200).send({
     token: customToken
   })`
8. On the client side login with the customToken. `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data.token)`

Is this summary a good practice or are there better ways to handle this?

Comment: Yup, looks good to me. A few comments though: (1) Storing the uid a d token in local storage is not really necessary, (2) passing the uid to your custom server is also not necessary since you can get the uid from the token itself (it looks like you do this in step 5 anyway), and (3) you may not need to use custom tokens here. Depending on your use case, you could in theory store the premiumAccount: true stuff in /users/$uid and then use a rule like "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('premiumAccount').val() === true" instead of "auth.token.premiumAccount === true".